# Selenium PageObjects variable handling

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm fairly sure this is a simple one but I'm not finding the answer.

I have a script which is written using PageObjects. This is all controlled by a master "Run Test" class and runs off to several Page Object Classes.

Now the problem I am incurring is I need to pick up a system generated variable in Step 3 of my script and then use it in Step 5 however this variable is not being passed to that class.

What am I doing wrong?

Main Class

```
class RunTest
    {

        static IWebDriver driver;
        string PlanID; <- Tried setting here?

        //Opens Chrome, Navigates to CTSuite, Logs in and Selects desired environment. 
        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void Login()
        {
         ... Login Code
        }
        [Test]
        public void Test5()
        {


            //Set back to home page
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ajaxLoader']")).Click();

            var NetChange = new SwapNetwork(driver);
            NetChange.ChangeTheNetwork("LEBC");

            var SearchForClient = new GoTo(driver);
            SearchForClient.GoToClient("810797");

            var NewContract = new NewContracts(driver);
            NewContract.AddNewContract("Test5", PlanID); //PlanID is set in this class

            var NewFee = new NewFee(driver);
            NewFee.AddNewFee("Test5");

            var StartChecks = new NewFee(driver);
            StartChecks.ExpectationChecks("Test5", PlanID); //Then needs to be used here
        }
```

Variable is set by

```
//Collect plan reference number
            string PlanReference = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_MainBody_Tabpanel1_lblRecord']")).Text;
            Console.WriteLine("Plan Details: " + PlanReference);
            var StringLength = PlanReference.Length;
            PlanID = PlanReference.Substring(StringLength - 7, 7);
```

With in 
`public void AddNewContract(string testName, string PlanID)`

First line in the StartCheck class is a `Console.Writeline` for the plan ID but it always returns nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing `PlanID = PlanReference.Substring(StringLength - 7, 7);` you set the value of the local variable passed to this method. It has no effect on the `PlanID` variable in `RunTest`. You nee to return the new value and assign it

```
string planID = PlanReference.Substring(StringLength - 7, 7);
return planID;

// or if you don't need it in the method just
return PlanReference.Substring(StringLength - 7, 7);
```

And in `RunTest`

```
PlanID = NewContract.AddNewContract("Test5"); // no need to send PlanID
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but I am getting this error on the return line 'Since 'NewContracts.AddNewContract(string)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression'

Comment: @Smithy7876 so change `void` to `string`

Comment: Ah I did not know I could do it like that. Opens up a whole new world of possibilities! Thanks!